# SQL-UNION of two SELECT of different column number yields null value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

So I am currently working with the EVE Static Database Export, and have run into a snag when trying to report a list of values that I need for the rest of my program.  I am currently trying to get the typeID, name, waste, and quantity required for a blueprint using the following:

```
SELECT typeid,name,waste,greatest(0,sum(quantity)) quantity FROM ( 
    SELECT invTypes.typeid typeid,invTypes.typeName name,null AS waste,quantity 
    FROM invTypes,invTypeMaterials 
    WHERE invTypeMaterials.materialTypeID=invTypes.typeID 
    and invTypeMaterials.TypeID=@paramID 
  UNION 
    SELECT invTypes.typeid typeid,invTypes.typeName name,invBlueprintTypes.wasteFactor 
    waste, invTypeMaterials.quantity*r.quantity*-1 quantity 
    FROM invTypes,invTypeMaterials,ramTypeRequirements r,invBlueprintTypes 
    WHERE invTypeMaterials.materialTypeID=invTypes.typeID 
    and invTypeMaterials.TypeID =r.requiredTypeID 
    and r.typeID = invBlueprintTypes.blueprintTypeID and r.activityID = 1 
    and invBlueprintTypes.productTypeID=@paramID and r.recycle=1 
) t GROUP BY typeid,name
```

Now, this SQL was adapted from a previous set of code that did not return the waste value.  wasteFactor is stored inside of the invBlueprintTypes table of the database.  Whenever I run my program and use this function (I have a separate set of code that loads the values into a C# List array, and currently just ignore acquisition of the "name" value) waste always comes back as a null value.  I am assuming this is because I am doing "null AS waste", but I am unaware as to how merge the two SELECT functions without this, as the first SELECT only originally had 3 values selected for.  I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone had an idea as how I should go about adjusting my code, as I'm fairly new to SQL, and this is a bit beyond my scope of knowledge.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT typeid,name,max(waste),greatest(0,sum(quantity)) quantity FROM (  ....
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using (Union) replace it by (Union All)

Comment: Adding a union all would have multiple records, that is not ideal mate.